# Как тренировать бота на Dialogflow автоматически?

Tags: dialogflow

Эксперементирую с гугловой нейронкой `Dialogflow` для бота. Хочу понять как можно тренеровать ее используя готовые тексты. Тут есть раздел Traning в который можно загружать `txt` файлы по фразе на строчку, но как начать тренировку по этим данным не понимаю. Как обучать, говоря боту где он ответил правильно, а где нет в ручную - понятно. А как автоматизировать этот процесс?

Comment: Добрый вечер, Павел! Сам столкнулся с такой проблемой, не могу автоматизировать обучение. Нужно программировать, насколько я знаю.

Comment: в виду специфики SO тут не вполне корректным будет переписываться. У меня в профиле есть ссылка на ВК. С удовольствием составлю компанию в исследовании этой темы.